# garbage character is getting exported on the folloowing regex

Tags: regex

i want to extract the category id from the response message. the regex i had used is `categoryId=(.*?)>`

I am doing this on the following response messages. can you please correct me like what is going wrong here ?

```
<a href="/jpetstore/shop/viewCategory.shtml?categoryId=FISH"><img border="0" src="../images/sm_fish.gif" /></a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: `categoryId=([^"]+)"`

`[^"]` matches any character, which is not in the list. So, in this case everything, but `"`

Answer (score 1):

Try this regex:

```
categoryId=(.*?)"
```

This uses the non greedy operator to make sure that it only matches the content between the `categoryId` label and the ending quotation.

Comment: i am getting  [1649-1653] `FISH` as a result .. what is that number denotes

Comment: Where are you running this regex?  You never told us in your OP.  However, I tested the above regex using the regex101.com site and it worked fine.

Comment: i also tried on that site only .. 1. [55-59] `FISH` ... what is this number denotes

Comment: OK...the numbers denote the character positions of the input string which matches.  So it means that `FISH` is characters 55 to 59 of your input string.  These numbers are _not_ part of the actual regex match.

Comment: this does't match with all the tag id that i have in the response code

Comment: `<a href="/jpetstore/shop/viewCategory.shtml?categoryId=FISH"><img border="0" src="../images/sm_fish.gif" /></a>
<img border="0" src="../images/separator.gif" />
<a href="/jpetstore/shop/viewCategory.shtml?categoryId=DOGS"><img border="0" src="../images/sm_dogs.gif" /></a>
<img border="0" src="../images/separator.gif" />
<a href="/jpetstore/shop/viewCategory.shtml?categoryId=REPTILES"><img border="0" src="../images/sm_reptiles.gif" /></a>
<img border="0" src="../images/separator.gif" />
`

Comment: any comment on this ?

Comment: categoryId=BIRDS&id=1438131011240" .. i have one more condition to check ... like i should avoid &id=1438131011240 in that regex .. how to ignore this

Comment: got it ..categoryId=(.*?)& is the answer